# Get content between 2 words

Tags: php

I wanna get the contents (text) between two words(`word1` and `word2`), for example :

`word1blablabla Poetry can be divided into several genres, or categories. word2 blablabla`

so the contents = `blablabla Poetry can be divided into several genres, or categories.`

but, the problems sometimes the `word1` and `word2` can be in upper-case letter or in lower-case letter. And the other problem is the `word1` still be printed in the result. It should be printed. How to handle that problem? thank you :)

here's the code :

```
$file = 'word1 blablabla word1 Poetry can be divided into several genres, or categories. word2 blablabla ';
$word1='word1';
$word2='word2';
$between  = substr($file, strpos($file, $word1), strpos($file, $word2) - strpos($file, $word1));
```

Comment: @RegisteredUser why? using preg_match is better than using stripos ? thanks

Comment: Regular expressions (`preg_match`) are more powerful and flexible, with the ability to match complex patterns of text. In this case, `stripos()` sufficiently addresses the letter case issue, so you don't need the added complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) instead of `strpos`:

> stripos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a
>   case-insensitive substring in a string

Comment: OH, thank you.. ! The other problem is the `word1` still be printed in the result.

Comment: `stripos()` returns the position where the first word _begins_... thus, to exclude it, add its length to the begin offset of your result: `substr($file, stripos($file, $word1) + strlen($word1), ...)`

Comment: @CoreXii `word1` consist of 5 letters. so I shoul be `substr($file, (stripos($file, $word1)+5)` does it right? cmiiw

Comment: It's always better to use dynamic code like `strlen($word1)` than to hardcore magic numbers into your application. You'll come back later and wonder "why is this 5 here?".

Comment: @CoreXii oh, silly me, I didn't read your first comment carefully about `strlen`. yes, I got it, thank you !